# catalog entry json has api specification error

Tags: bluedata

I have created an application image for BlueData and deployed it to the app store.

I noticed in tooltips on the app icon (App Store) the following error:

> catalog entry json has api specification error

What can be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the `catalog_api_version` in the json file.

It should have been version 5 - [api matrices](http://docs.bluedata.com/awb34_api-matrices)